# Symfony 3, join двух таблиц

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3, doctrine2

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно соединить две таблици и посчитать при этом колличество сообщений у каждого пользователя.

Есть два класса и соответствующием им таблицы.
User и Message нужно посчитать сколько у каждого пользователя сообщений.
Я реализовал вот такой метод

```
 public function сountUserMessagesQueryBuilder()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('Message')
        ->select('COUNT(Message.id)', 'User.id')
        ->join('UserBundle\Entity\User', 'User',  Join::WITH,
            'Message.user = User.id')

        ->groupBy('User.id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
```

Но, собственно он у меня не работает. В чем может быть проблема или как мне модифицировать запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот мой запрос делает  аналогичные действия. Только водит данные виде массива. Я полагаю пример наглядный.

```
//Находим всех агентов у которых на текущий период есть план 
    $employeesWithTargets = $em->getRepository('NitraSchemaCDBBundle:Employee')->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u.employeeNumber, COUNT(t.id) as targetCount')
        ->InnerJoin('u.monthPlans','m')
        ->innerJoin('m.target','t')
        ->andWhere('t.month = :month')
        ->andWhere('t.year = :year')
        ->andWhere('t.country = :country')
        ->andWhere('u.employeeNumber is not null')
        ->setParameters(array( 'month' => $month, 'year' => $year, 'country' => $countryID  ))
        ->groupBy('u.employeeNumber')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: я уже на самом деле сам разобрался, но за пример большое спасибо, так как он более чем наглядный:)